# What are the advantages of bridging from iOS to an UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, native

I'm a beginner to the iOS app development and I tried to implement an UI using UIWebView. What are the features of this approach?

What are the features of `Bridging From iOS to an UIWebView`?